# Can anyone help me to understand how Spring 4 works in this example?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn springFramwork 4  so i donwloaded a test project, i installed sts (spring tools) but what i didn't undertand .
look at the servlet-context.xml
i cut it to see the exact part

```
 <beans:beanclass="
      org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" /> 

   </beans:beans>
```

after that there is a HomeController , i can't find any mapping related to this controller , so how can he use it to de request

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "login";
}
```

this was a request example that actualy works if we call the login.jsp

so please can anyone explain to me how this things works or give me a tutorial . thanks

Comment: can you show HomeController code?

Answer (score 1):

When you start the application, this line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />
```

tells spring to scan this package (com.journaldev.spring) for annotated classes(@Controller in your case). After that spring "parses" the  @RequestMapping annotations to fint the url that is mapped to this method and class.

Answer (score 0):

When you give `<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />` spring scans for all classes in this package and sub packages for classes that is annotated with `@Controller` and registers it.

The with `@RequestMapping` matching requests get routed to this controller and to appropriate methods.

When you do a return String its actually getting mapped to a view via the view resolver. Since  you have configured view InternalResourceViewResolver it'll take the sting login and prefix and suffix with the values configured and try to locate that page.. In your example

```
"/WEB-INF/views/" + "login" + ".jsp"
```

resulting in a look up for

```
/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
```

You could get plenty of tutorials by just googling it. Some simple ones are

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/

http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/